# powershell - replace line in .txt file

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell and I need replace a line in a .txt file.

The .txt file always has different number at the end of the line.

For example:

```
...............................txt (first)....................................

appversion= 10.10.1



............................txt (a second time)................................

appversion= 10.10.2


...............................txt (third)...................................

appversion= 10.10.5
```

---

I need to replace `appversion` + number behind it (the number is always different). I have set the required value in variable.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you wanting to replace all `appversion= 10.10.X` with the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of this issue you are getting, which I see from your comments, is that you are trying to replace text in a file and saved it back to the *same* file while you are *still reading it*.

I will try to show a similar solution while addressing this. Again we are going to use `-replace`s functionality as an array operator.

```
$NewVersion = "Awesome"
$filecontent = Get-Content C:\temp\file.txt
$filecontent -replace '(^appversion=.*\.).*',"`$1$NewVersion" | Set-Content C:\temp\file.txt
```

This regex will match lines starting with "appversion=" and everything up until the last period. Since we are storing the text in memory we can write it back to the same file. Change `$NewVersion` to a number ... unless that is your versioning structure.

**Not sure about what numbers you are keeping**

About which part of the numbers, if any, you are trying to preserve. If you intend to change the whole number then you can just `.*\.` to  a space. That way you ignore everything after the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with regex.
Let call `$myString` and `$verNumber` the variables with text and version number

```
$myString = "appversion= 10.10.1";
$verNumber = 7;
```

You can use `-replace` operator to get the version part and replace only last subversion number this way

```
$mystring -replace 'appversion= (\d+).(\d+).(\d+)', "appversion= `$1.`$2.$verNumber";
```

Comment: (gc c:\test.txt) -replace 'appversion=(/d)',"appversion= $FolderName" |
Set-content c:\test.txt

Comment: Is `gc c:\test.txt` returning you a string or an object?

Comment: so you should get the text, try `gc c:\test.txt -raw`
I suggest you to split your code, instead of using pipe save each step in a variable and check step by step what is wrong